# Finding array length in postgres

Tags: arrays, postgresql, greenplum, postgresql-8.2

I tried `array_upper(array(Value))`   and `array_upper((Value):array[])`  but was getting syntax error.

Value : data type is int [];
I am expecting the result as below table:

```
 Pname  week_date      Value    array_length
    5773    6/8/2013    {29}            1
    5773    3/30/2013   {27}            1
    5773    3/16/2013   {138,3,4}       3
    5773    3/9/2013    {37,8}          2
    5773    1/19/2013   {66}            1
    5773    1/5/2013    {49,50,50,56}   4
```

But this works fine

```
select array_upper(array[1,2,3,6], 1)
```

I need to use Value column and find out the length of that value array

postgres version : 8.2

Comment: 8.2 is past end of life. You need to upgrade.

Comment: I cannot as I am using green plum and it runs on 8.2 postgres by default.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That should work:

```
select array_upper ( value, 1 ) from table_name_here;
```

Note: 'VALUE' is reserved keyword in SQL, so it is not recommended to use it as a column name. See: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html

Comment: no it doesnt work it throws an error : function array_upper(integer[]) does not exist

Comment: @user2569524: PostgreSQL 8.2 has [`array_upper(anyarray,int)`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/interactive/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) so it should work. Your error message suggests that you're trying to use `array_upper(value)` instead of `array_upper(value, 1)`.